# GAS Function 'getSheetValues' Return the wrong value for seconds

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form that dumps into a spreadsheet and I'm trying to use the timestamp as a unique identifier for reading and writing from the form responses.  I use the onFormSubmit function (run from the spreadsheet) to capture the response, turn it into an object, add some additional values, send an email, and return those values back to the spreadsheet.

However when I got to save those values to the spreadsheet, and I'm searching for the row with the matching timestamp, I'm running into an issue where the getSheetValues function returns values for the times in the spreadsheet one second off, but only some of the time.  This is not an issue with time zones (as many other posts are concerned with) but the spreadsheet actually reporting what is contained within the cells.

Here are the values from the spreadsheet (when viewing it directly):

```
Timestamp   Type of Time Off    Reason For Request  Start Date   End Date   Status  Email ID    Request ID  Reviewed by Reviewed Timestamp  Reviewed Reason
4/29/2014 10:06:41  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014                       
4/29/2014 10:08:08  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014                       
4/29/2014 10:09:10  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014   Pending 145add16569c73e2                
4/29/2014 10:11:22  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014                       
4/29/2014 10:12:13  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014                       
4/29/2014 10:13:25  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014                       
4/29/2014 10:13:53  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014   Pending 145add5b5f926a16    2           
4/29/2014 10:14:17  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014                       
4/29/2014 10:16:36  Vacation Day    I would like some time off  4/29/2014   4/30/2014
```

And here are the values returned by getSheetValues called on that range:

```
[
[Timestamp, Type of Time Off, Reason For Request, Start Date, End Date, Status, Email ID, Request ID, Reviewed by, Reviewed Timestamp, Reviewed Reason], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:06:40 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, , , , , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:08:07 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, , , , , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:09:10 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Pending, 145add16569c73e2, , , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:11:21 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, , , , , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:12:12 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, , , , , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:13:24 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, , , , , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:13:53 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Pending, 145add5b5f926a16, 2.0, , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:14:16 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, , , , , , ], 
[Tue Apr 29 10:16:35 GMT-04:00 2014, Vacation Day, I would like some time off, Tue Apr 29 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2014, , , , , , ]
]
```

As you can see, not just some, but most of the times are off by a second.  The trailing values after the two that match are from me saving additional values related to that request back to the spreadsheet (where the timestamps were effectively matched).

Is this a known issue?  Is there something with the way that GAS (or google spreadsheet) interprets dates that is throwing this off?  Some sort of rounding? Any advice or workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to cast the timestamp as a number instead of a date for comparison purposes.

Do you have a sheet you can share with the code you are using?  I need to see exactly what's happening to identify a solution.

Comment: Even if it works using the number (of milliseconds since 1970) it still seems to be a rounding bug in GAS.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the date object is stored the same way in both contexts, just displayed differently. Google Sheets is rounding the number of seconds while JavaScript's `Date.toString()` is taking the floor.

For example, "1/1/2014 12:00:00.750" is shown as "1/1/2014 12:00:01" in Google Sheets using the default date/time formatting. If you instead use a custom cell format that includes the milliseconds value then the seconds will change back to "00". In your code you are converting the Date object to a String, and that code doesn't round the value, but instead shows "Wed Jan 01 12:00:00 GMT-05:00 2014".

I don't think either behavior is strictly wrong, they are just different. As mentioned above, you may need to compare values not based on the strings but on the underlying timestamp. Alternatively, use another method to find the row you are interested in (perhaps `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()`).